# Filtering data on multiple csv files - python - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This is my first question on stackoverflow. I have just started to learn python 2 months ago.
I had a look on this site and others, but I can't find a solution to my problem.
I'm trying to speed up an annoying data filtering task I have to do everytime for my job.
I want to use pandas library to read multiple .csv files (12 to be precise) and assign for each one a variable (df_1, df_2,...,df_12) that correspond to a new filtered dataframe.
Each .csv file contain the raw data of a tensile test from one of the company Instron machine we have in the Lab.

Example:

[first .csv file with raw data, first 9 rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rqsfb.png)

I will use the filtered dataframe to do some other analysis with Minitab software.

This is what I managed to do so far:

```
import pandas as pd

dataset_1 = pd.read_csv('Specimen_RawData_1.csv')
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'X': dataset_1.iloc[1:,-1].values,
                   'y': dataset_1.iloc[1:, 2].values,
                    })

df_1 = df_1.loc[df_1['X'].isin(['1.0', '2.0', '3.0', '4.0', '5.0'])]
```

The code will take the last column and assign to X, and take the third column and assign to y.
X will be then filtered asking to keep only the value equal to 1,2,3,4,5.

This works for the first .csv file. I can copy and paste it 12 times, but I thought that using a list or a dictionary may help instead.
I understand I can't create variables in a loop.

I have failed so far because the dictionary I have created takes the variables as strings so I can't use them for data analysis.

Any idea, please?
Thank You

Comment: Could You provide sample data and result You are going to obtain please? Tried to understand the idea but failed :-)

Comment: I have edited the question. Hope is more clear. Thank You for your interest.